# All my browsers search hijacked

Tags: macos, firefox, safari

I've run into a known problem, which is when Firefox's default search for some reason changes. Mine changed to http://assist2.searchguide.frontier.com/search?qo=&rn=n9HuoSl_-11Ytte . Resetting all the user preferences didn't do anything for it. The about page looked right and looking in it for strings similar to the website I get directed to gave no result. I tried opening Safari and its search now has the same problem. I'm on Mac OS Lion. I don't know what else to try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your address bar, type in: `about:config`

Inside of the filter search box, type in:
`browser.search.defaultenginename`

Double click that entry (or right click and choose “Modify”) and then type in the name of the search engine you wish to have as the default search engine. It must be one that you already have installed and also make sure you type in the name correctly.

Now if you type in “Google” or “Yahoo”, restart Firefox and when your browser comes back up you will see the the search engine you choose as your default search engine.